# iphone dev tools?

Tags: iphone, development-environment

whats the best and simplest tool to use for iphone development?

i am a .net web developer and use Visual Studio for ever. what would i use for developing iPhone apps?

is this different than developing websites for mobile devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xcode - "It's not the *best* tool - it's the *only* tool".

Seriously.

Comment: +1, developer.apple.com to download the environment and SDK.  Need to be running on an Intel Mac OSX 10.6

Answer (score 1):

Re being the "only"; that is just not the case; tools like [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/) allow you to develop for iPhone in C# / MonoDevelop, using the device-native widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Ya.. Xcode is the only tool in which u can develop source codes for all the apple products. Being a .net profession, you can get the concepts of Objective C and Cocoa soon. Please refer to the following Apple developer website for futher details about iPhone development.

[Apple Developer.](http://developer.apple.com/resources/)